# document.execCommand - insertParagraph isn't working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to toggle the application of `<p>...</p>` tag around the selection in a contentEditable, for which I'm using

```
document.execCommand('insertParagraph', false, null);
```

Forget about toggling the p-tag, I'm not able to apply the tag to the selection. Instead, it is giving

```
<div>
    <br>
</div>
<div>
    <br>
</div>
```

This is happening with all the browsers (chrome, firefox, IE). It is removing the selection and creating the above empty divs.

Comment: In what browser?

Comment: This is happening for all the browsers.. forgot to mention in my question

Answer (score 3):

I know its bit late but i found the solution

```
document.execCommand('formatblock',false,'p');
```

It worked for me in both chrome and firefox.